# Why I got "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb2" when using " matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, decode

I ran a code of Gaussian Diffusion Model, everything was OK until the visualization part, where `plt.pcolor(x,y,np.mean(C1,axis=2)*1e6, cmap='jet');` didn't work and it suggested that `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 8: invalid start byte`

I tried to add "ignore" for "decode", but it didn't work

```py
import numpy as np
import sys
from scipy.special import erfcinv as erfcinv
import tqdm as tqdm
import time

from gauss_func import gauss_func

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
## for Palatino and other serif fonts use:
#rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['Palatino']})
rc('text', usetex=True)


# SECTION 1: Configuration

# SECTION 2: Act on the configuration information

# SECTION 3: Main loop

# SECTION 4: Post process / output
# output the plots
   plt.figure()
   plt.ion()

   plt.pcolor(x,y,np.mean(C1,axis=2)*1e6, cmap='jet');
   plt.clim((0, 1e2));
   plt.title(stability_str + '\n' + wind_dir_str);
   plt.xlabel('x (metres)');
   plt.ylabel('y (metres)');
   cb1=plt.colorbar();
   cb1.set_label('$\mu$ g m$^{-3}$');
   plt.show()
```

Error received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\jmwu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py", line 341, in __call__
    return printer(obj)

  File "C:\Users\jmwu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py", line 244, in <lambda>
    png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))

  File "C:\Users\jmwu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py", line 128, in print_figure
    fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)

  File "C:\Users\jmwu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2049, in print_figure
    **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\jmwu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 510, in print_png
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)

  File "C:\Users\jmwu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 402, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)

  File "C:\Users\jmwu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\jmwu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1649, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)

  File "C:\Users\jmwu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)

  File "C:\Users\jmwu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\jmwu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2628, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)

  File "C:\Users\jmwu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)

  File "C:\Users\jmwu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\jmwu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1187, in draw
    renderer)

  File "C:\Users\jmwu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1125, in _get_tick_bboxes
    extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)

  File "C:\Users\jmwu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 930, in get_window_extent
    bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)

  File "C:\Users\jmwu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 313, in _get_layout
    ismath=ismath)

  File "C:\Users\jmwu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 209, in get_text_width_height_descent
    s, fontsize, renderer=self)

  File "C:\Users\jmwu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 464, in get_text_width_height_descent
    dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)

  File "C:\Users\jmwu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 328, in make_dvi
    texfile], tex)

  File "C:\Users\jmwu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 307, in _run_checked_subprocess
    exc=exc.output.decode('utf-8')))

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 8: invalid start byte

<Figure size 432x288 with 2 Axes>
```

Comment: there seems to be a lot of irrelevant code there, could you trim your example down to be a closer to a [minimum complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  at a guess it's related to your titles having non-ASCII characters in, but difficult to tell as there's so much else going on

Comment: Do you get this error if you don't use TeX?

Comment: I refine the code and I guess the problem lies inMatplotlib’s LaTeX support. I will try to add a Latex environment. Thank you all.